# WSO2 Gadget Server: url-pattern in servlet filter does not work as expected

Tags: wso2

I want to establish the WSO2 Gadget Server in version `wso2GadgetServer-1.4.2` (Carbon 3.2.x) in an environment secured by a Tivoli Access Manager (WebSEAL). All authenticated requests which reaches the gadget server have the parameter `iv-user` filled (with the username) in the HTTP header. The infrastructure environment has some restrictions: In opposition to the functionality of the WebSEAL authenticator plugin provided by WSO2 (as declared in the article [“WebSEAL authentication for WSO2 Carbon based products”](http://blog.facilelogin.com/2009/04/webseal-authentication-for-wso2-carbon.html)) there is no additional communication between TAM and the gadget server and no special TAM user account possible. The gadget server should evalute the header and automatically log in the user if necessary. Under normal circumstances the end-user should never see the login mask of the gadget server. It would be nice, if the necessary changes could be done without changing and compiling the gadget server. After studying the article [“Carbon Authentication Framework”](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.de/2011/08/carbon-authentication-framework.html), I have tried to write an own authenticator plugin with BE and FE services to replace the default gadget server authentication.

My approach is, to lead through all HTTP requests to a filter where I can inspect the HTTP header and log in the user if necessary. In difference to the examples I’ve followed where only a single url is catched (article [“How to create redirector in WSO2 Stratos”](http://sanjeewamalalgoda.blogspot.de/2010/11/how-to-create-redirector-in-wso2.html) and the source code of the “SAML2 SSO Authenticator” provided by WSO2), I want to catch all requests. I have set the url-pattern in the servlet to `"/*"`, with the result, that my filter logic will not be called. If I use an url-pattern for one single site (e.g. `"/carbon/admin/docs/about.html"`), then the filter logic will be reached.

Why does the url-pattern `"/*"` not work as I expect?